# SimpleSAMLphp installation in Windows Apache

Tags: php, windows, apache, simplesamlphp

I want to install SimpleSAMLphp in windows Apache/Xampp. Let me tell you what did so far:
1. I have downloaded latest stable version from https://simplesamlphp.org/download and placed the unzipped file in Apache folder, i.e. C:\Apache24\simplesamlphp directory contains composer.json. I have downloaded dependencies as well.
2. Now when I am going to setup the vhost as shows in the site 6. Configuring Apache section as

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName localhost
        DocumentRoot C:/Apache24/htdocs
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName service.example.com
        DocumentRoot C:/Apache24/service.example.com

        Alias /simplesaml C:/Apache24/simplesamlphp/www
</VirtualHost>
```

3. Changed the config file.

Now the problem:
I am unable to open the Alias in browser. And running httpd.exe in browser shows error about the example.com does not exist.

Need help if anyone have setup SimpleSAMLphp in Windows, please share your steps and vhosting configurations. It would help I think lot of peoples.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are those errors exactly?

Comment: Waning: Directory service.example.com does not exist

Comment: I have Xampp setup with *:80 as localhost, so what should be the vhsot conf for simplesamlphp?

Comment: Hi "ogondza", kindly verify my answer. I will be oblized. Also if there is any other configuration possible, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am sorry, that I was doing some mistake...
I am going to add one vhost, rather in Windows Xampp, there is one file /xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf. Need to add one Alias below /phpmyadmin statement:

```
Alias /simplesaml "C:/xampp/simplesamlphp/www"
<Directory "C:/xampp/simplesamlphp/www">
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Now restart server and hit http://localhost/simplesaml/ and all you go...

All windows xampp users if faced configure simplesaml...might be helped.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else who is trying to set up SimpleSAMLphp on a Window's version of xampp, here are the steps I took to get it running.

1. Install xampp. For this example, I've installed to: "c:\xampp"
2. Download and unzip SimpleSAMLphp to htdocs folder ("c:\xampp\htdocs\simplesamlphp"). It will probably extract with version numbers appended to the end, so I've renamed the folder to 'simplesamlphp' in this example.
3. Add the alias and directory from the answer above into the httpd-xampp.conf file, but change both "C:/xampp/simplesamlphp/www" to "C:/xampp/htdocs/simplesamlphp/www".
4. Start Apache server and in your browser, go to: "localhost/simplesaml"
   This assumes that there are no exotic entries in your hosts file.

You should now see the SimpleSAMLphp Installation Page.